# Determine the weak convergence if applicable determine the weak limit

Tags: probability, probability-theory

$ (\mu_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ is a probability measure on $(\mathbb{R}, \cal{B}(\mathbb{\mathbb{R}}))$

$$ \mu_{n}(\{k\})=\frac{{\lambda_n}^{k}}{k!}e^{-\lambda_{n}} \ ,k \in\mathbb{N_0}$$
and $\lambda_{n} \rightarrow \lambda, n \rightarrow \infty $ whereby $\lambda_n,\lambda>0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

I'm still very new in the probability theorem and I still have problems with the whole concept of using weak convergence. I have checked out some similar exercises but I'm extremely struggling how to solve this problem I would really appreciate any kind of answers.

Comment: Do you mean $\exp(-\lambda_n)$ instead of $\exp(-k)$ in your displayed formula?  If not, is $\mu_n$ really a probability measure?

Comment: thank you I have corrected my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PMF of $\mu_n$ is $\mu_n(k) = \frac{\lambda_n^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda_n} \to \frac{\lambda^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda} =: \mu(k)$. Note that $\mu$ is also a PMF. By the generalized DCT (or [Scheffe's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheff%C3%A9%27s_lemma)), $\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}|\mu_n(k) - \mu(k)| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. This implies that $\sup_{B \subset \mathbb{R}}|\mu_n(B) - \mu(B)| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. This conclusion is stronger than weak convergence $\mu_n \to_d \mu$.